# How to declare an object as private

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am using following code to create an object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sales_object IS OBJECT (
  dates DATE, 
  product_id VARCHAR2(20), 
  product_name VARCHAR2(50), 
  sale DECIMAL(15,2)
);
```

which I am using to create a table with following code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE year_sales_tab IS TABLE OF sales_object;
```

Now this table is being used in a function to store and return a grid.

If there is any way to create the **sales_object** as private?

Comment: can an object be private?

Answer (score 0):

> If there is any way to create the sales_object as private?

Yes.

Instead of creating type sales_object as **OBJECT**, create it as a **RECORD** in the **package** and use it in your code. When you create as an object, it is stored in the database, while if you create as a record, it could only be used in your code not elsewhere.

```
TYPE sales_object
IS
  RECORD
  (
    DATES        DATE,
    PRODUCT_ID   VARCHAR2(20),
    PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    sale         DECIMAL(15,2) 
  );
```

**Update** OP is actually talking about the privileges.

You could simply create the type by logging as the user to which you want the privileges to e given, by doing only the current user will have the owner privileges, while other users cannot access the object.

If you are intending to grant privilege to specific users, then

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON "USER"."TYPENAME" TO "OTHER_USER";
```

Comment: Its giving the following warning

`Encountered the symbol "RECORD" when expecting one of the following: array varray table object fixed varying opaque sparse The symbol "object was inserted before "RECORD" to continue.`


 I just want that this object being created in my schema should not be accessible in another schema.

Comment: If you want this kind of schema level privacy, it all depends upon GRANTS you provide. If access GRANTS are given to other USERS they can use otherwise they CAN'T.

Comment: Its always better to use ROLES for providing these kind of Privileges. Providing direct user level grants mess up the DB a lot.

Comment: I agree, but just for one object that too for one user, doesn't make much of a difference to the DBA maintaining the database. Also, the level of question is surely not for production environment.